# Paso de 2 parametros de action a vista

Tags: zend

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña web, con *Zend framework 2*.

La verdad es que llevo intentando pasar dos parametros de un *Controller/Action* a una vista, el caso es que en la vista `Login.phtml` del *action* `loginAction()` 
los parámetros están ahí (60,nav).

```
<h1>  <?php echo $this->tipocli;?></h1>
<h1>  <?php echo $this->codcli;?></h1>
```

De la vista `login.phtml` los paso al *Action* con `basePath()`, de esta forma:

```
<td><a class="colorlink "href="<?php echo $this->basePath("/alta/areapersonal/opciones/".$this->tipocli."/".$this->codcli)?>">opciones</a></td>
```

Y en el *Action* opciones (*opcionesAction*), los recibo así, para posteriormente
enviarlos  a la vista `opciones.html` con *ViewModel()*.

```
public function opcionesAction() {      
    $tipocli= $this->params()->fromRoute("id",0);
    $codcli=(string)$this->params()->fromRoute("id2",0);

    return new ViewModel(array("tipocli"=>$tipocli,"codcli"=>$codcli));     
}
```

Pero en la vista solo me esta pasando un parametro!

```
<?php
echo "Tipo: ".$this->tipocli;
echo "Cod : ".$this->codcli;  // Tipo:60 Cod:0
?>
```

Llevo toda la tarde, que hago mal, además me esta pasando el código cliente como si fuera el tipo!, y en la url están los dos:

> http://localhost/nombreweb/public/alta/areapersonal/**opciones/nav/60**

Agradecería alguna ayuda, muchas gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Hola serenimus, en primer lugar te recomiendo hacer el [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer como funciona Stackoverflow. En segundo lugar me surge una pregunta sobre `<?php echo $this->**tipocli**;?>` ¿por qué usas los *? es un claro error de sintaxis.

Comment: Por otra parte, ¿cómo está configurado el _route_ para aceptar esos parámetros? Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir la configuración _route_. También probaría dentro de _opcionesAction_ a poner un `var_dump([$tipocli, $codcli])` antes del _return_ y ver que salida da para comprobar que el action recibe el parámetro correctamente.

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por tu respuesta. Los **, son errores que cometí al añadir el "post" en el foro. Hice un var_dump, en opcionesAction(), como tu me dijiste,y me pasa lo mismo que antes, me toma el código de cliente (60), como el tipo de cliente (que es "nav") y el tipo de cliente, como "0" (cero)     string 'Tipo: 60' (length=8)
string 'Cod: 0' (length=6)

Comment: public function opcionesAction(){
   
   $tipocli= $this->params()->fromRoute("id",0);
   $codcli=(string)$this->params()->fromRoute("id2",0);
    
   var_dump([$tipocli,$codcli]);
return new   ViewModel(array("tipocli"=>$tipocli,"codcli"=>$codcli));                       
 
   
  }

Comment: tambien debes definir en tu router los parametros que recibira el view

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista parece un problema con la configuración del *route* del módulo.

Entra en el directorio del módulo en cuestión (*Application* o el que tengas configurado). Voy a suponer que sea el módulo *Application* con una estructura similar a esta:

```
.
├── public
└── zf_project
    ├── config
    └── module
        └── Application
            └── config
                └── module.config
```

Si abres el archivo de configuración del módulo, dentro del *array* debería haber una de las *key* que se llama *router* para configurar la estructura de las rutas y a dónde se dirigen cuando hay coincidencias.

Un ejemplo simple de un *router* de una sola ruta aceptando dos parámetros.

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'       => '/alta/areapersonal/opciones/:tipocli/:codcli[/]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'tipocli' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                        'codcli'  => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults'    => [
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Areapersonal',
                        'action'        => 'opciones',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

> Solo como consejo, cuando armas las rutas, los parámetros que recibes deberían ser lo más identificativos posible. Si esperas recibir un parámetro mixto, intenta buscar el nombre que mejor lo identifique. Si esperas recibir solo el tipo de *cli*, nómbralo como *tipocli*.

Dicho esto, el *Action* quedaría de esta forma:

```
public function opcionesAction()
{
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();

    $viewModel->setVariables([
        "tipocli" => $this->params()->fromRoute("tipocli", 0),
        "codcli"  => $this->params()->fromRoute("codcli", 0),
    ]);

    return $viewModel;
}
```

> Todos los datos que llegan desde el *router* llegan como *string*

```
$codcli=(string)$this->params()->fromRoute("id2",0);
        ^^^^^^^^ -> Esto no es necesario
```

Y en la vista con esto:

```
<?php
echo "Tipo: " . $this->tipocli;
echo "Cod : " . $this->codcli;
?>
```

Y una *url* relativa así: `/alta/areapersonal/opciones/nav/60`.

Deberías obtener un resultado así:

> Tipo: nav
>   Cod : 60

Prueba y me comentas. Si algo no queda claro, coméntame e intentaré aclararlo.

Answer (score 0):

**muchas gracias a todos** aquellos que se han molestado en mirar mi post e intentar ayudarme.
Mi error de novato ha sido, configurar el route así:

'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]**[/:id][/:id]**]',

en lugar de así:

'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]**[/:id][/:id2]**]',

Por ello, al intentar recoger los parametros,solo me tomaba uno,"descolocado" y 
el otro como cero

public function opcionesAction(){

```
        $tipocli= $this->params()->fromRoute("id",0);
        $codcli= $this->params()->fromRoute("id2",0);

        return new ViewModel(array("tipocli"=>$tipocli,"codcli"=>$codcli));




    }
```

gracias de nuevo...gran comunidad!!